# How to query documents and get them in a key value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to query all the documents from `resultInDB` and get them in the manner given in `expectedResult` snippet.

```
resultInDB:
 [
   {
     _id:1,
     owners: [
               "johnDoe",
                "michael"
             ],
     stakeholders: [
                    "johnDoe",
                    "david"
                   ]
   },
   {
     _id:2,
     owners: [
                "michael"
             ],
     stakeholders: [
                    "michael",
                    "david"
                   ]
   }
 ]
```

expectedResult:

```
{
   "johnDoe" :{_id:[1]},
   "michael" :{_id:[1,2]}
   "david" :{_id:[1,2]}  
 }
```

As you can see in the result am expecting it has to be key/value for every users from either from owners or stakeHolders into a key and the id's that each user is associated with.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I couldn't come up with a proper query for this, the query I tried just get's the unit list
`db.getCollection('company').aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "usersList":{$reduce:{input: {$concatArrays: ["owners","stakeHolders"]}, initialValue:[], in: {$setUnion: ['$$value', '$$this']}}},
      "ids": "$id",
    }
  }
])`

Comment: Please edit you question to give code examples.

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {name: {$setUnion: ["$owners", "$stakeholders"]}}},
  {$unwind: "$name"},
  {$group: {_id: "$name", doc: {$push: "$_id"}}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, res: {$push: {k: "$_id", v: {_id: "$doc"}}}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$res"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SU8UiBvRxBZ)